# Set Javascript Time & TimeZone from SQL database and asp.net codebehind page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field in my database which states the timezone of the user. It is an integer field so anything > 0 is a + hour.

I need to display two separate times on the users screen

e.g.

Your time is: "just get the current computer time"

The other users time is: "get the current computer time then either add or subtract hours based on the database record"

I can do the database side of things I just need help with the Javascript element. For demonstration purposes I am happy for you to hard code the offset

The time must update automatically every 60 seconds to reflect the new minute and hour

Thanks

Comment: You realise there is a +13 and +14 as well?

Comment: Just for being bad - there are regions with fractions of hours. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone

Comment: @Lloyd sorry what i meant to say is its a number not a string. Theoretically it can be -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,648 as long as its a number :)

Comment: question updated to avoid confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the hours on the date object in JavaScript. For example:

```
var date = new Date();

date.setHours((new Date()).getHours() - 5);
```

It will also try and be clever and make adjustments for you, as MDN says:

> If a parameter you specify is outside of the expected range, setHours
>   attempts to update the date information in the Date object
>   accordingly. For example, if you use 100 for secondsValue, the minutes
>   will be incremented by 1 (min + 1), and 40 will be used for seconds.

You can use `setInterval` to perform the update. Here's a more complete example:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var local = new Date();
    var remote = new Date();

    remote.setHours(local.getHours() - 5);

    $('#time-local').html(local.toGMTString());
    $('#time-ny').html(remote.toGMTString());
},1000);
```

Comment: Thanks - How can I just display hh:mm:ss and also update in realtime?

Comment: It updates in realtime using `setInterval`. You can use MomentJS to better format the output - http://momentjs.com/

Comment: that looks great and absolutely spot on. Trouble is, my JS skills are non-existent so wouldnt even know where to begin!

Comment: any chance you can help finalise this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/cH84e/ ? Thanks